# How to have multiple cameras in a manim 3D Scene

Tags: manim

I'm looking for a setup in manim (0.8.0 CE) where I have in the main part of the screen an ambiente camera plus two addtional views on the right hand side (like a picture in picture, or split screen) from a fixed diffrent angle on the scene. I've found a MultiCamera Class, but this is fixed to a MovingCamera. I assume that I need additional three_d_camera objects, but couldn't find any example in any of the tutorials which points me in the right direction. Are there any ideas how to do this?